# Artinian Submodule of Free module over PID

Tags: principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

> Let $F$ be a field, $P$ a $F[x]$-submodule of $F[x]^n$.
>  Suppose $M=F[x]^n/P$ is Artinian.
>   **Claim** M is finite dimensional over $F$.

**Attempt**
Since $F[x]$ is PID, and $M$ finitely generated,
\begin{equation}
M \cong F[x]^r\oplus F[x]/(p_1)\oplus \cdots\oplus F[x]/(p_k)
\end{equation} 
by Classification Theorem. If $r>0$, $M$ cannot be Artinian. Hence $M$ is f.d. over $F$.

**Question** If I am not mistaken, submodule of a free module is free (over PID). 
Isn't that imply $P\cong F[x]^n$ and $M\equiv0$? What I am missing here?

Comment: Simply that if $P\simeq F[x]^n$, it is not the canonical injection which is this isomotphism. Counter-example: the ideal $n\mathbf Z$ is isomorphic  to $\mathbf Z$, yet $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\ne 0$.

Comment: It make sense now, thanks for clarification @Bernard.